# R: predict.averaging is not taking an offset into account when plotting

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models

I'm currently trying to use the `predict.averaging` function in MuMIn to create some graphs from some model averaging I've done on some GLMMs. I'm interested in whether the number of insects caught per daylight hour in some traps changes when the traps are left out for different lengths of time;  I included `offset(log(Daylight))` in my GLMMs to account for this. But when I use the `predict` function it doesn't take the offset into account and I get the same graph that I get if I hadn't included the offset in the first place. But I know the offset is having an effect due to the output from my model averaged GLMMs, and it's the kind of effect I would expect from observations of my data.

Does anyone know why this problem might be and how I might make  `predict.averaging` take the offset into account? I've included the code that I'm using below:

```
# global model for total insect abundance
glmm11 <- glmmadmb(Total_polls ~ Max_temp+Wind+Precipitation+Veg_height+Season+Year+log(Mean.nectar+1)+I(log(Nectar+1)-log(Mean.nectar+1))+Pan_colour*Assoc_col+Treatment*Area*Depth+(1|Transect)+offset(log(Daylight)), data = ab, zeroInflation = FALSE, family = "nbinom")

# make predictions based on model averaging output (subset delta < 2)
preds<-predict(ave21, full = F, type = "response", backtransform = FALSE) # on the response scale
```

Where ave21 is a model averaging object generated using `pdredge` and `model.avg` that was constrained to have the offset in every model: `model11 <- pdredge(glmm11, cluster = clust, fixed = ~offset(log(Daylight))+(1|Transect))`. The object itself looks like this:

```
Call:
model.avg(object = get.models(object = model11, subset = delta < 
2))

Component model call: 
glmmadmb(formula = Total_polls ~ <3 unique rhs>, data = ab, family = nbinom, 
zeroInflation = FALSE)

Component models: 
                              df  logLik    AICc delta weight
1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12    20 -864.14 1769.22  0.00   0.47
1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13 23 -861.39 1770.03  0.81   0.31
1/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12      19 -865.97 1770.79  1.57   0.21

Term codes:                                  

                                Area                              Assoc_col                                         
                                1                                         2 
                                Depth I(log(Nectar + 1) - log(Mean.nectar + 1)) 
                                    3                                         4 
                             Max_temp                                Pan_colour 
                                    5                                         6 
                               Season                                 Treatment 
                                    7                                         8 
                                 Year                      log(Mean.nectar + 1) 
                                    9                                        10 
                offset(log(Daylight))                                Area:Depth 
                                   11                                        12 
                 Assoc_col:Pan_colour 
                                   13
```

Which I then used to get predictions:

```
pred_results<-cbind(glmm21$frame, preds) # append original dataframe to predictions
plot(pred_results$preds~pred_results$Treatment) # Treatment = trap duration (hours)
```

This code might go around the houses a little as I borrowed it off of a fellow PhD student. The graph I get when I plot my predictions looks like this:[Model predictions vs. Trap duration (hours)][1], which is very different from the view given by the summary results of my model averaging:

> (conditional average)

```
               Estimate  Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)  -5.896725   0.948102    0.949386   6.211  < 2e-16 ***
 Treatment24  -0.714283   0.130226    0.130403   5.478  < 2e-16 ***
 Treatment48  -0.983881   0.122416    0.122582   8.026  < 2e-16 ***
```

Any help would be great, as I can't find any specific instances where this has been addressed on the site to date. Thank you in advance and please let me know if you need me to add anything to make this question better.

Tom

> [1]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn4dK.jpg

Comment: Your code does not reveal what `ave21` is. What component models it includes? Do they have the term `offset(log(Daylight))` at all?

Comment: Hi @KamilBarton - sorry about that, I've edited my post. I constrained my `pdredge` to always have the offset within each model using the `fixed =` argument. If you need any more information from me then let me know, and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: I could not replicate this problem with mock data. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I imagine this means that I've done/missed something a little silly. I've attached a link containing the model averaging object (ave21.Rda), some basic data to replicate the GLMM/data frame (ab-global.csv) and the code that I was using: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cbpizwbhobynj9o/AACMupukhRpyCfU7NuX2uB_6a?dl=0 - sorry that it's in Dropbox, I wasn't sure how to attach it otherwise...

Comment: I've compared the output from `predict` to prediction calculated by hand and still I cannot see anything suspicious. Offset is clearly included in the prediction.
Note that `predict.averaging` cannot use conditional averaged-coefficients  (it gives a warning about argument "full" being ignored). BTW do you use an up-to-date version?

Comment: Re Kamil's comment. Is there 1) reason that `predict.averaging()` cannot use conditional coefs? 2) is there any plan to allow it to use the conditional coefs?